# Optimize Wordpress Database Design

Tags: database, wordpress, meta

I'm using WordPress real estate theme.
There are too many posts in post-meta table.
Each property post produces more than 20 metas and go in that post meta table.
So, if I have about 1million properties there might be more than 20 millions rows in post meta table.
And. I think it might take longer to query post meta.
Is there anyway to maintain database better than usual ways for wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is removing unnecessary Posts and meta associated with it!
But If you want to keep it all and work on database side,
A simple plugin like [WP-Sweep](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-sweep/) will help in cleaning up and optimising the tables  in your database.
Remember: always back up your database before you perform any maintenance